# How do I bind ComboBox with WPF and get SelectedItem?

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm, data-binding, combobox

I am sorry I am asking question on stack over flow first time so might be some thing i done wrong.

I have started learning WPF MVVM and I'm stuck.

I have one parameter master table in a database, and it has the columns `parameterid`, `parametername`, `parametertype`. It is populated with master data, e.g., country master has `parametertype` "country", city has "city" `parametertype`, but `parameterid` will be unique.

Now I have a customer page, where in the customerviewmodel object I have `countryId` and `CityId` parameters to be saved inside the customer object.

1. How can I bind this `parameterId` directly with `customer.CountryId` from XAML? Or is that not possible?

   Currently I have achieved it as follows: defined one `CountrySelectedItem` Property and bound it with combobox `SelectedItem`. When its property changes, when anyone changes its value then in viewmodel I set the Customer's `CountryId` in `CountrySelectedItem` set property.
2. How do I validate the Customer's `countryID` property? In the combo box, I have bound the Parameter Master's object so can't write data Annotation's Required attribute to the Parameter Master Entity.

Here are the complete Scenario
    public class Customer
    {

```
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
}
<telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="cmCountryId" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                                     ItemsSource="{Binding LstCountry}"
                                                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                                                     DisplayMemberPath="ParameterName" 
                                                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountry,Mode=TwoWay}"  Height="25" Width="200" >
 </telerik:RadComboBox>


 /* To Fill DropDown Country DropDown From ParameterMaster*/
 public List<ParameterEntity> LstCountry { get; set; }

 LstContainerType = new List<ParameterEntity>(parameterService.GetParamterTypeDetail("COUNTRY").ToList());
 /*
  Parameter Master has ParameterId,ParameterName,ParameterType -- All Master Data Stored Inside It with Different ParameterType.      
  */
/* When User Select CountrId then I Set It's ParameterID As CountryID In My CustomerEntity  */
  public ParameterEntity SelectedCountry
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedCountry;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedCountry = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCountry");
            SelectedCustomerEntity.CountryId = _selectedCountry != null ? _selectedCountry.ParameterId : 0;
        }
    }
So Here Is my question for above Scneraio.

1) To Bind Customer Object's CountryId Property From CountryDropDown is that any other option available then this one.
   SelectedCustomerEntity.CountryId = _selectedCountry != null ? _selectedCountry.ParameterId : 0;
   //  please have a look SelectedCountry property.
   Something like , I do not need to write Selected Property and i Can Directly Set ParameterId To CountryId Of CustomerEntity From XAML
   Or this one is right scneario.

2) Another Question Is How To do Validation On CountryId ComboBox.
   i mean As Mention in CustomerEntity has Required CountryId But In XAMl Design of  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountry,Mode=TwoWay}" 
   What should i write to display if user has not select any country from dropdown. Should I write a logic on Save Button manully ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by making an assumption that your creating a form that will have a submit button on it that will save the selected data in some manor.

For the combobox, you can use the SelectedValuePath to select a field from the type you are binding as your selections.

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCountry}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}"
    SelectedValuePath="ParameterId" />
```

Then your SelectedCountry property in your view model will be set to the ParameterId.

For the second question of validation as well as how to bind to the `Customer.CountryId`in your submit function on your model you would first check if SelectedCountry is null or empty then error out showing the validation error message. Otherwise set the `Customer.CountryId = SelectedCountry` and save the customer.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggetion and help , But I have updated my question and just added scenario please let me know is that ok or not